# How can I stop a dwarf with no arms from trying to store items?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

One of my dwarfs lost both her arms in a valiant effort to defend the fortress.

Although I'm grateful for her effort, I now get spammed with messages saying "cancels Stored Owned Item: Too injured. Is there anyway from stopping her trying to store items?

Comment: bah, the only use for a dwarf with no arms is the gladiator pit!

Comment: Dwarf Fortress is a gruesome game.

Comment: Every time I see a question like this about [tag:dwarf-fortress] I think "wow, d.f. is deep, there are 'dwarfs with no arms' in it too!"

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: I came here just to say that, too! And everytime I think `I seriously need to start playing this`.

Comment: That's exactly how I started playing, after seeing questions being asked here. Extremely steep learning curve, but well worth it.

Comment: Stories of dwarf maiming and !!FUN!! is exactly why I persisted trying to learn to play the game, otherwise I would've given up shortly after my first attempt.

Comment: The title sounds like it ought to be the first line of a riddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kill her or try to suppress the announcements.

I suppose you already deactivated hauling labors so that won't work.

Comment: I went with killing her in the end. Turning of hauling labors didn't work as she still tried to store her own items.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could just turn off all manual labor jobs. I guess that would be an opportunity to create the most socially adept dwarf ever.

Comment: Indeed. In my current fortress a similar *Look ma! No hands!* dwarf veteran successfully campaigned for a mayor.

Answer (score 1):

Take away that dwarf's bedroom.  There will be no place to store a personal item then.